# Java good practice - Declarations of interface types instead of declarations of implementation types

Tags: java, types, encapsulation

In "O'Reilly - Programming Android" they recommend avoiding this code:

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
```

but to replace it with this:

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
```

They argue it's easier to maintain code if later the type of `a` should be changed to say a linked list. If so, why not make it of type `Collection`, or even `Object`?

I feel that as the instantiation must be changed to change its type, surely it's better to keep it type restricted as much as possible and change the extra line if needed.

Are they correct?

Comment: It's more convention than anything else. But convention is important.

Comment: It will make much more sense when you start creating your own large projects. By using interfaces it is much easier to test isolated classes than if you hard coded to the implementation, and also will make it much easier to upgrade your application modules later.

Comment: You must be kidding, @TomHawtin-tackline.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels What, you're going to mock out `ArrayList`s? Do you want to do `String` whilst you're at it?

Comment: I would describe this as a "kind-of sort-of vaguely good-like practice." Yes, it's kind of nice to declare your variables with the type whose interface you need, not the type implementing that interface-- but it's not a problem, not something worth complaining about or even noticing if people don't do it.

Comment: @TomHawtin: No, I'm not talking so much about standard Java classes, but you'd better be sure that I'll mock out my view and control while I work on my Model, and visa versa for the other components. Coding to the interface will make it easier for me to do this, but I'd be surprised if this is new to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my personal opinion you should use the interface as high (in hierarchy) as possible and have the operations you will need.

In some cases you need just to store objects, iterate, and get them using index. `List` interface is providing that. Object does not provide you with these methods.

Using `Object` - you will make your code less readable and there could be cast exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

They are correct.

You should use the most restricted type possible. If `Collection` is the right abstraction for you, instead of `List` or `Set`, then use it instead. If you need to use something as an `Object`, then by all means, refer to it as an `Object`. But if you need to be more specific, then just be more specific. The trick is to avoid casting when it's not necessary.

As you have mentioned, the idea is to hide implementation details when you don't want them to be exposed. This makes your software easier to use and more maintainable. For example, if you have a method that returns a `List`, then someone using your software doesn't have to worry about what implementation of `List` it really is. This helps make your software easier to understand. Now, because of this, you are free to change which type of `List` you return with out (for the most part) hurting programs that call that method.

Comment: You wouldn't need to use `Set` much, would you?

Comment: @TomHawtin, Why not? A `Set` implies that there are no duplicate elements and that order of the elements doesn't matter. If those are your requirements, then `Set` is the best choice because `Collection` doesn't imply those characteristics. I don't mean to imply that the methods defined on the interface is all that matters.

Comment: But then so does `ArrayList` over `List`.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're talking about? If ArrayList is what you need, then use it instead of List. What are you disagreeing with?

Comment: Helier For any sensible usage of a `List` you want the guarantees, if not the methods, provided by the likes of `ArrayList`. In the same way for any sensible usage of `Set` you'd want the guarantees provided by the likes of `HashSet`. If you just care about the methods and not the guarantees, then you can always use `Collection` instead of `Set`. There is an inherent need to use `Set`, but there is a convention.

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't do anything useful with an `Object` reference.

Answer (score 0):

They are wrong.

If a type appears in a public API, it should be as general as semantics allows.

```
List<String> getStringList();
```

As an implementation detail, the type should be as specific as the programmer knows.

```
ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Disagree. If all you need are methods on the interface, you should code to the interface. The only time you might want to use the implementation is when you need to tweak something in the same scope that isn't available on the public interface (in the case of ArrayList, pretty much all accessible methods are also on the public interface).