# Incompatible types - SortedSet and TreeSet

Tags: java

When I try to compile this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class NameIndex
{
    private SortedMap<String,SortedSet<Integer>> table;

    public NameIndex()
    {
        this.table = new TreeMap<String,TreeSet<Integer>>();
    }
}
```

I get:

```
Incompatible types - found java.util.TreeMap<java.lang.String,java.util.TreeSet<java.lang.Integer>> but expected java.util.String,java.util.SortedSet<java.lang.Integer>>
```

Any idea why?

UPDATE:
This compiles:

```
public class NameIndex
{
    private SortedMap<String,TreeSet<Integer>> table;

    public NameIndex()
    {
        this.table = new TreeMap<String,TreeSet<Integer>>();
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is `List<Dog>` a subclass of `List<Animal>`? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicit)

Comment: Yes - taking a look at this question I think I agree. My understanding is, from reading this question, that you can't have one generic as an interface and the other generic as a concrete class. They have to be the same.

Comment: Just FYI, in the case of using Kotlin you can easily run into this because `sortedSetOf<T>()` returns `TreeSet<T>` whereas `Collection<T>.toSortedSet()` returns `SortedSet<T>`, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20972.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
this.table = new TreeMap<String, SortedSet<Integer>>();
```

You can specify the *actual* type of the values in the map when you add elements to it, meanwhile you must use the same types used at the time of declaring the attribute (namely `String` and `SortedSet<Integer>`).

For example, this will work when adding new key/value pairs to the map:

```
table.put("key", new TreeSet<Integer>());
```

Answer (score 1):

Always type an object with the interface instead of the concrete type. So you should have:

```
private Map<String, Set<Integer>> table;
```

instead of what you have right now. The advantage is that you can switch out implementations whenever you want now.

Then:

```
this.table = new TreeMap<String, Set<Integer>>();
```

You get a compile-time error because `SortedSet` and `TreeSet` are different types, although they implement the same interface (`Set`).

Comment: SortedSet is an interface which is why I used it in the declaration of table. I then expected to use a concrete type (e.g. TreeSet) to implement. But that didn't compile. So, I had to specify a concrete type (i.e. TreeSet) both times. Which is what's confusing me.

Comment: The compile-time error caused the generics, not the outer types. `TreeMap` is a valid subtype (implementation) of `SortedMap`.

Comment: @CheeseWarlock You're right. I mixed up the Map and the Set. Fixing.

Answer (score 1):

You can always declare:

```
private SortedMap<String, ? extends SortedSet<Integer>> table;
```

but I suggest using:

```
private Map<String, ? extends Set<Integer>> table; // or without '? extends'
```

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10656019/639753) question

Comment: I would suggest `? extends SortedSet<Integer>` since in the original notation in the question suggests the internal set is a `TreeSet` not just a set.

Comment: I believe that `SortedSet` and `Set` are both interfaces, therefore, by declaring `? extends SortedSet` I think you wouldn't be compromising the principle of programming to interfaces and not to implementation. Plus, the contract for `SortedSet` is different from that from `Set`, and it has a few additional methods available in its public interface not available in the simple `Set`.

Comment: @edalorzo I agree with you completely. Providing `SortedSet` in declaration depends on how he will use this field later on.